# Удалить элементы из muliline textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

В `textbox` есть 10 строк. Как удалить первые три элемента? Есть вариант копировать `textbox` в `List<string>` и там все менять, но думаю есть более элегантный вариант.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду `В textbox есть 10 элементов.`? Значит, там 10 строк? Или 10 символов? Или что-то другое?

Comment: 10 строк....................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно получить коллекцию строк, и копировать все кроме первых трех.

```
var lines = textbox.Lines;
var lastLines = lines.Skip(3);
textbox.Lines = lastLines.ToArray();
```